# Can you alias a tuple type?

Tags: tuples, alias, ceylon

I'm playing around with Ceylon and I'm trying to create an alias for a tuple. The following do not work:

```
class MyPair(Integer i, Float f) => [i, f];
class MyPair(Integer i, Float f) => [Integer, Float](i, f);
class MyPair(Integer i, Float f) => 
        Tuple<Integer|Float, Integer, Tuple<Float, Float, Empty>>(i, [f]);
class MyPair(Integer i, Float f) => 
        Tuple<Integer|Float, Integer, Tuple<Integer|Float, Float, Empty>>(i, [f]);
class MyPair(Integer i, Float f) => 
        Tuple<Integer|Float,Integer,Tuple<Float,Float,Empty>>(i, Tuple<Float,Float,Empty>(f, []));
```

The error I get on the first two revolves around the use of brackets:

```
Incorrect syntax: missing statement-ending ; at [ expecting statement-ending ;
```

There are two separate errors on the second:

Some variation of

```
Alias parameter distance must be assignable to corresponding class parameter rest: Integer is not assignable to [Integer]
```

on `class MyPair` and

```
Argument must be a parameter reference to distance
```

on `f`, `[f]`, or the tuple construction.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Although I found a solution, I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, the instantiation expression on the RHS of the `=>` in a class alias declaration is currently extremely restricted, not by design, but just because it will take some extra work to implement full support for arbitrary instantiation expressions in the compiler *backends*.

But what I would actually do for now would be to use a regular type `alias`, like this:

```
alias MyPair => [Integer,Float];
```

And use it like this:

```
MyPair pair = [1, 1.0];
```

I think that's actually even cleaner than using a `class` alias.

HTH.

Comment: Aha, didn't know that was possible. My understanding of [the tour](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.1/tour/typeinference/) led me to believe that a regular `alias` can only be used with intersection and union types.

Comment: You can use `alias` with any legal type, actually. The difference is that you can't use an `alias` everywhere you can use a `class` alias—in particular, you can't use it in an `extends` clause, and you can't use it in an instantiation expression. But since in this case: `Tuple` is `final` anyway, so that's not actually an additional restriction, and you can't really improve on the nice `[x,y]` syntax for instantiation either.

Answer (score 2):

After tinkering around a bit I came across

```
class MyPair(Integer i, [Float] f) => 
        Tuple<Integer|Float, Integer, Tuple<Float, Float, Empty>>(i, f);
```

which works.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do much better than your solution, but you can at least use a shortcut for the `Rest` type parameter:

```
class Pair([Integer i, [Float] f]) => Tuple<Integer|Float, Integer, [Float]>(i, f);
```

You're limited here because the parameter types of your class alias must match the parameter types of the class that you're aliasing. If I'm interpreting the [spec](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/current/spec/html_single/index.html#classaliases) correctly:

> *Note: currently the compiler imposes a restriction that the callable type of the aliased class must be assignable to the callable type of the class alias. **This restriction will be removed in future.***

then this might work in subsequent releases:

```
class Pair(Integer i, Float f) => Tuple<Integer|Float, Integer, [Float]>(i, [f]);
```

or *maybe* even:

```
class Pair(Integer i, Float f) => [i, f];
```

Then again, if your aim is to [destructure](http://ceylon-lang.org/blog/2014/12/29/destructuring/) a tuple, Ceylon 1.2 will let you do that directly:

```
value [i, f] = [2, 0.5];
```

Comment: Thank you! My actual goal was to do something like `class Pair(shared Integer i, shared Float f) => [i, f]` to alias the elements of the pair to a different name. It looks like the only way to achieve that is with a fully fledged class. I understand that feature would be hard to implement in general (what happens if there's an attribute in tuple named `i` with a different type?), but I was hoping for a shortcut.

Comment: @Jeffrey Are you sure destructuring isn't what you're looking for? Maybe you could update your question with an example of how you'd be using your `Pair` class.

Comment: Destructuring would probably work just as well, except I'm still using 1.1.

Comment: Well, something to look forward to then.